# Use HTTPS in the Flask Application or in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, https, flask

I want to use HTTPS in a flask application, but I am not sure what's the best approach. Should I enforce my application to use HTTPS as described in this http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/111/ or should I use HTTPS through Nginx?

Does anyone know any possible security issues that might occur in both of these approaches?

Answer (score 4):

**Terminate HTTPS in Nginx.**

If you are running a small deployment, this won't matter much, but if you scale up it will be almost impossible to maintain an implementation where SSL is handled by Flask.

With enough traffic, you will run into the need to run several Flask instances. When that happens, you will need to use a load balancer. If you terminate on the LB, you need to update and maintain one certificate when it expires. If you terminate on Flask, your effort grows with every instance.

From a security perspective, storing the certificate and key on only one instance (the LB) is better than having them on several instances as well.